# ngx paypal works in development but in production it shows error

Tags: angular, paypal, angular8

I run ng build --prod and it shows the error...

[image: Error Console]

> ERROR in node_modules/ngx-paypal/lib/components/paypal.component.d.ts(27,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

Comment: I started using ngx-paypal a few days ago with ng8, and ran into the error during dev builds. SO solution at 60092642 works for me - dev and prod.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this exact issue - the solution appeared to be downgrade to an earlier version. I am running Angular 8 and 5.0.0 seems to work well for that version.